# Expo EAS build (iOS) failing when Authenticating with Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, windows, react-native, expo, eas

Hello I've just purchased an **Apple Developer Account** for my Expo Projects and when I create an iOS build `eas device:create` I get this error:

```
× Logging in...
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Socket connection timeout
    Error: device:create command failed.
```

**Also**, I'm using a windows pc hoping to use Expo EAS Services.

I want to Authenticate my Apple ID to Expo EAS Services to create iOS Builds